# i have a login view in django.i need to redirect to my url page after successful log in

Tags: django, django-views

```
#views.py
def login(request):  
    ctx=dict()  
    ctx['login_form'] = LoginForm()  
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        for e in Login.objects.all():  
            if e.password==request.POST['password']:  
               redirect_to('my url')
        return HttpResponse('failed authentication ')  
    return render_to_response('registration/login.html', ctx, context_instance = RequestContext(request))  


#urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',

   (r'^signup/', signup),
    (r'^$', index),
    (r'^ajaxsite/', signup),
    (r'^login/', login),

)
```

Comment: Why don't you use djangos build in auth module?

Comment: Quite apart from that, checking password by getting all objects And iterating through to see if the passwords match is insane. What if you get 10million users? What if two users have the same password? And why aren't you even hashing the passwords?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Actually   i'm new comer in django.What do you prefer to how to check username and password without getting all objects.

Answer (score 2):

use redirect https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

```
return redirect(new_url)
```

or if it is an ajax submit,

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(new_url)
```

Comment: thanks...  return HttpResponseRedirect(new_url) will solve my problem.